# Compiling two interdependent files in Intellij Idea

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea

I have two groovy files (in case you are not familiar with groovy, think of it as a java file).

I have file A.groovy in package `test.BI`. This file has makes use of a class `Master` which is in B.groovy which is also in the package `test.BI`. However this B.groovy also makes use of a class `Execution` which is in A.groovy.

When I compile A.groovy it errors `unable to resolve class Master` and when I compile B.groovy it errors `unable to resolve class Execution`.

Both A.groovy & B.groovy have multiple classes. How can I solve this problem without creating one file for each class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IntelliJ IDEA, invoke Make (Ctrl+F9), or Compile (Ctrl+Shift+F9) on just these two files (after selecting them both in the Project View).

Comment: Ah, thanks. Any idea how I might be able to compile them  from command line. Although what you suggested works from IDE if I try  to `groovyc A.groovy`, I get the same error.